# cURL - how can I turn into a variable

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am using the companieshouse API to get a list of companies by name. The cURL returns something like the below screenshot

[image]

How can I get one data field from this, for example `title` (company name)

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=wdmr",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"curl -xG88ZE9p3D2ip6pxbbthlQLKdHqxFful0_3fHSSq: https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: XXX",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Code, not image. -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please enter your code to we write it based on your requirements and code

but anyway, your answer is:

you need to decode it with decodition functions such as: unserialize, json_decode, and ....

at first you should see what is the return output type of your api. if it's json use following code:

```
$output = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($output['items'] as $company){
    echo($company['title'] . PHP_EOL);
}
```

for saving titles (as you asked):

```
$titles = array();
$output = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($output['items'] as $company){
    $titles[] = $company['title'];
}
print_r($titles);
```

Comment: Excellent! That does work. Is there a way to `($company['title'] . PHP_EOL);` into a variable? Such as `$CompanyName=($company['title'] . PHP_EOL);`?

Comment: you can put your needles into an array or other way that you think is correct. i edited my post and add an example for your ask